# Unit testing a static C++ library using a higher level language?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd

I want to write some static C++ libraries in a test-driven style.

I started looking around for C++ unit test frameworks, bu then I wondered why I needed to write test code in C++ at all.

It should be possible to call static C++ libraries from a higher level language where it would be easier to write the tests.

Is this a sensible thought?

Is there any particular language that makes this particularly simple? Whether that's Python, Lua or something else? Even perhaps a special DSL for it?

Any hints for good tutorials?

Comment: In the end, you are asking for library or tools recommendation, don't you. Which renders your question off topic. Even if not, I think your request is too broad/opinionated. Having said that; I think you still would want to have **some** tests in C++. Your usecase "it should be a library" ... that you then can use from other languages/frameworks ... is down the road. When you do real TDD, you start with functions that should do **one** thing. Making sure that you can invoke that function say from a python script adds quite some complexity on top of that.

Comment: In other words: I dont see how you could do real TDD when your "first" test would be to have a script that tries to invoke C++ code.

Comment: Finally: python/lua... scripts would make a nice integration test, but not for true unit tests and tdd.

Comment: I'm trying NOT to make it a tool recommendation. I want a more general answer to the question. But yes, a pointer to the tools that would let me do it would be helpful. I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to unit test individual functions or do tdd writing tests in the other language. Just as long as there isn't too much cost having to write some kind of integration wrapper.

Comment: You ask "is there a particular language to do that". In other words "is there a tool to do it". And then you ask for tutorials?! That is asking for recommendations, nothing else. Beyond that: you said you want to TDD. TDD lives from small, minimal tests, which are then resolved by writing minimal amounts of production code. As said: the gap between your C++ prod code and potential script tests is far too wide imho.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your C++ code from some other language with some language bindings has some consequences on how you can test.

With tests written in C++, your test code will be closer to real client code.  Which means, that all C++ specific compile time effects will take place, like, macro expansion, integer promotion of arguments, overloading resolution, inlining, template instantiation etc.  And, this would happen individually for every single test case written in C++ where you call your library.

In contrast, when testing from a different language, you will have to bind the C++ functions/methods etc. to symbols or whatever of that other language (probably with wrapper functions in-between).  The compilation of these language bindings is then the only point where all the abovementioned compile time effects take place.

Whether these consequences of using a different language are OK (or even desirable) for you or not depends on your test goals, and thus you will have to judge it.